# How to connect to Databricks Delta tables from QlikView?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, qlikview, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I need to create QlikView Dashboard using data in databricks Delta Lakes. Has anyone tried connecting to DBFS using from a QlikView dashboard? I usually use JDBC connection string to connect to DBFS from my scala code. For that I use Spark Simba JDBC driver. Do i need to install this driver for qlikview connection too?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by executing the following steps on qlikview server:

1. Download Simba ODBC Driver
2. Create user DSN using ODBC data source set up wizard (64 bit/32 bit depending on machine's config)
3. Use following detals for the same:

   Host: databricks hostname

   port: 443

   username: token

   password: Personal Access Token created using databricks admin console

   in SSL options section: Make sure enable SSL is checked

   in http options section: enter http path value   advanced settings>
4. Test the connection
5. User this DSN in qlikview/qliksense edit script to connect to DB